# Vertical lines to points in scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose I have a set of points `x` and a set of corresponding data `y`. I now plot these in a scatter plot, `plt.scatter(x,y)`. The figure I get contains some x axis tick generated by matplotlib. Is there a way I can attain the automatic ticking, but to add vertical lines from the x-axis to the point in the scatter and label them?

Comment: explain your question, please

Comment: If you can add a figure of the desired output would be great

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Like this?

[image: altered scattergram]

If so then here are the essentials.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import collections as matcoll

x = np.arange(1,13)
y = [15,14,15,18,21,25,27,26,24,20,18,16]

lines = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    pair=[(x[i],0), (x[i], y[i])]
    lines.append(pair)

linecoll = matcoll.LineCollection(lines)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(linecoll)

plt.scatter(x,y)

plt.xticks(x)
plt.ylim(0,30)

plt.show()
```

Addendum:

For coloured dot, replace `plt.scatter(x,y)` with:

```
colours = ['Crimson', 'Blue', 'Fuchsia', 'Gold', 'Green', 'Tomato', 'Indigo', 'Turquoise', 'Brown', 'Wheat', 'Yellow',]
plt.scatter(x,y,c=colours)
```

- For optional ways of specifying colours see [specifying colours](https://matplotlib.org/users/colors.html).
- For a list of X11 colour names and their corresponding hex codes see [X11 colours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names).
- Note that matplotlib seems to dislike two word colour names such as 'Hot Pink'.

Addendum 2:

The easiest way, depending on requirements, might be to use the suggestion offered in the second answer, suitably adapted.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
from random import randint

x = [datetime(2019, 6, i) for i in range(1,21)]
y = [randint(10,20) for i in range(1,21)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
plt.xticks(rotation=90) 
ax.stem(x, y, markerfmt=' ')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please see answer addendum.

Comment: if the x axis is in DateTime format then how to format this code? because matcoll is taking only float and not datetime objects.

Answer (score 28):

Well, there is a [`stem`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.stem) method, much easier to use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x, y = np.random.random((2, 20))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.stem(x, y, markerfmt=' ')
plt.show()
```

If you want bullets on the top of lines, just remove `markerfmt`.

[image]

Comment: Excellent. I had to add a `basefmt` to prevent the horizontal axis to be red. `ax.stem(fs, amps, basefmt= 'C0', markerfmt=' ')`