# Matplotlib how to draw vertical line between two Y points

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I have 2 y points for each x points. I can draw the plot with this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0, 2, 4, 6]
y = [(1, 5), (1, 3), (2, 4), (2, 7)]


plt.plot(x, [i for (i,j) in y], 'rs', markersize = 4)
plt.plot(x, [j for (i,j) in y], 'bo', markersize = 4)

plt.xlim(xmin=-3, xmax=10)
plt.ylim(ymin=-1, ymax=10)

plt.xlabel('ID')
plt.ylabel('Class')
plt.show()
```

This is the output:

[image: Sample Plot]

How can I draw a thin line connecting each y point pair? Desired output is:

[image: Desired Output]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

just add
`plt.plot((x,x),([i for (i,j) in y], [j for (i,j) in y]),c='black')`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can also use [LineCollection](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/shapes_and_collections/line_collection.html). The solution below is adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40896356/4932316) answer.

```
from matplotlib import collections as matcoll

x = [0, 2, 4, 6]
y = [(1, 5), (1, 3), (2, 4), (2, 7)]

lines = []
for i, j in zip(x,y):
    pair = [(i, j[0]), (i, j[1])]
    lines.append(pair)

linecoll = matcoll.LineCollection(lines, colors='k')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, [i for (i,j) in y], 'rs', markersize = 4)
ax.plot(x, [j for (i,j) in y], 'bo', markersize = 4)
ax.add_collection(linecoll)
```

[image]